# Java 8 Iterator stream filter NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, iterator, java-stream

```
    public static double getAttackSpeed(ItemStack item) {
    Attributes ab = new Attributes(item);
    for(Attributes.Attribute attribute : ab.values())
        Flawlord.log(attribute.getName());
    return FlawlordHelper.stream(ab.values()).filter(a -> a.getAttributeType().equals(Attributes.AttributeType.GENERIC_ATTACK_SPEED)).findFirst().get().getAmount();
}
```

this doesnt work

```
    public static int getDamage(ItemStack item) {
    Attributes ab = new Attributes(item);
    int dmg = 0;
    for(Attributes.Attribute attribute : ab.values())
        if (attribute.getAttributeType() == Attributes.AttributeType.GENERIC_ATTACK_DAMAGE)
            dmg = (int) attribute.getAmount();
    return dmg;
}
```

this works

hello. can someone explain to me why the latter works, but the first not? maybe im just not getting it, idk. i think perhaps .equals() doesnt work here?

if i use the first one with lambda, i get an exception "NoSuchElementException: No value present".

Comment: How can we know ? What is a `FlawlordHelper` ? What's the code of `findFirst()` ?

Comment: That just means no value matched the predicate, and you tried calling `get()` on the absent `Optional`.

Comment: In what way does the second *"work"*? Does it simply not crash or does it produce a value value for `speed`?

Comment: the for loop gets the correct value. FlawlordHelper is StreamSupport to make Iterable to Stream. i just see i formatted it kinda bad and missed something sorry

Comment: Does ab.values create a new iterator every time you call it?

Comment: apparently the ab.values is empty. i misinterpreted a number. thanks tho, im just dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to call `get` on an `Optional` because there might be not result and a `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown which makes as bad as NPE, you can use `Optional.map` or `Optional.isPresent` instead.

`findFirst` returns an Optional because there is no guarantee that an element will be found.

Iterators are different, they only iterate if there is at least one element.

Answer (score 2):

If the list/iterator/stream does not contain an element which matches the filter then the `Optional` returned by `findFirst` will be empty and throw that exception if you access the value via `get`.

Comment: He said it works when finding the last one. If it were empty it would be for both.

Comment: @UDKOX I think the OP uses "first" and "latter" to refer to the stream and the for-loop code blocks.